# Computing Pearson Correlation in InfluxQL

Tags: influxdb, influxql, flux-influxdb

I want to compute the Pearson correlation in InfluxDB. I [found](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/pearsonr/) that there's a function for that in Flux.

I am using [Influx Query Language (InfluxQL)](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/). It is possible to compute the Pearson correlation in InfluxQL?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems there is no current plan to support this function natively. There is an [opening issue](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/792) for years and Flux has been give more priority than InfuxQL these days obviously, with constant iterations.